# Does using the @Autowired anno and never calling a set method on your bean provide thread safety even if you are using class level variables inside?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, thread-safety

So I am autowiring a service bean that I pass a map and it injects objects into it and returns it to my controller. Nowhere in my controller am I ever changing my bean, I send it info, and it returns me something. However, inside the bean, I am using class level variables in order to manage information as it moves around the class. Does this compromise thread safety?

Comment: Yes. Your controller will be called by multiple requests all modifying the same map.

Comment: @M.Deinum Even if none of the class level variables are present in the controller? They are only in my object that the data gets passed to.

Comment: If the bean is singleton scope (default) then it is not thread safe for the bean to have attributes which should be isolated for each request.  Concurrent requests to the controller delegate to the same bean instance shared across all the request threads.

Comment: If there is a singleton in your call stack which holds state you aren't thread safe. No matter if that is directly in the controller or a dependency of a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed class level variables, and begun passing the objects I need from method to method. Thank you for all of the input!